# Software (either local or online) for testing websites in browsers/operating systems

Tags: gratis, web-development, web-browser, software-testing, screenshot

I run Windows and wish to test a few sites in OS X, iPads, iPhones, etc. Are they any "free" places where I can get screenshots?

I have tried [CrossBrowserTool.com](http://www.crossbrowsertool.com/) which seems extremely slow and some images never arrive.

I have previously tried SauceLabs, but this is a paid service and they make videos. Even though this is paid, premium it still seems very slow and clunky.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I doubt any local tool can do this on a wide-enough range of devices.

Comment: Could you please add clear requirements: How many devices, after how much time all results must have appeared.